# Get the state of the Show Desktop toggle

Tags: command-line, unity, scripts, window, window-manager

I'm trying to get my touch gestures to behave like in Windows or Mac OS X. So that when I swipe up, I get the expose effect (Super-W) and when I swipe down, I get the desktop (Super-D).

However, after swiping down to show the desktop, a swipe up should first intuitively restore the desktop before showing all the windows, i.e. if the show desktop toggle is on, the swipe up effect should be altered to be Super-D as well.

In order to do this, I will need to tell what state the Show Desktop action is in.